# Storage Layouts - custom partitions with interactive selection for easy of update using autoinstall for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, autoinstall

We are looking to get below preseed file converted into autoinstall.

PRESEED Used for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm

d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
For LVM partitioning, you can select how much of the volume group to use
for logical volumes.

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string
boot-root ::
512 2000 2048 ext4
$primary{ } $bootable{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /boot }
.
2048 128 8192 linux-swap
$lvmok{ }
method{ swap } format{ }
.
5120 10000 -1 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ / }
.
5120 30000 25600 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /home }
.
1024 5000 4096 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /usr/local/safesquid }
.
5120 10000 8192 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /var/lib/safesquid }
.
512 5000 4096 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /opt/safesquid }
.
1024 5000 -1 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /var/cache/safesquid }
.
1024 45000 -1 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /var/log/safesquid }
.
512 16000 15360 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /var/www/safesquid }
.
2048 35000 -1 ext4
$lvmok{ }
method{ format } format{ }
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
mountpoint{ /var/db/safesquid }
.
```

Does autoinstall provides an option wherein the users can update the storage size for each partition using interactive menu.